# Help with Tag Synonyms, please!

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we engage a little more in keeping the tags clean and organized? Right now there are 4 tag synonym requests that have been sitting in the queue for a while now.

It's not the biggest deal in the world, but in the spirit of developing a thriving community *we need people who care* - who care about the menial, trivial things like tag synonyms that ultimately contribute to making the whole site a better place.

[*insert more eloquence here*]

So anyways, can we get some voters into the mix on creating or rejecting the tag synonyms?

[The list of pending synonyms](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is accessible from the bottom of the [tags page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags)

Comment: as a side note, I would eagerly vote (up or down, depends) the current synonyms except that I do not have the required score in several of the tags. I suspect this may be part of the reason there' so little action over there.

Comment: thank for brining this to my attention, I'll take a look at them asap

Comment: I don't see any solid evidence that the [synonym suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459/1438) system works on smaller sites.  A meta post seems to be the best solution as it gets community and moderator attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I approved bible-basis -> biblical-basis and book-of-genesis -> genesis as these are good synonyms correcting small mistags. I'm less sure about the others.

To address each: divinity -> god seems like a poor synonym to me. Even though they have similar meanings, it does not seem wise to merge them at this time.

On pneumatology -> holy-spirit I'd actually argue that if we are going to merge these tags then pneumatology should be the primary tag and holy-spirit be a synonym of that tag (like we've done with salvation -> sotieriology). We should be looking for the more academic term here.

Comment: I agree on divinity-->god, and the pneumatology/holyspirit idea seems good, too. My main concern was just drawing attention to the tag synonym page, as it seemed like no one cared. :) thanks!

Comment: @thomas yes, there isn't a prompt for mods (or other users) to be notified there are pending synonyms so its good to put it out there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the heads-up. I didn't know there were pending synonyms.  When there are pending edits or pending mod requests, I get a note at the top of the screen.  It's a bit odd that tag requests don't follow the same pattern.  I'll pass that along to the SO staff so that hopefully this doesn't get overlooked again.

Comment: The reason there isn't a notification system for these is that the are not binary done/undone states, they are supposed to be voted on by the community in an extended approval process. Until enough people check on there regularly, wee can step in as mods and push pending things through.